# MariaDB alter table row format doesn't work

Tags: mysql, database, mariadb

I need to change row format of a  table in MaraiaDB.##

I used 
     ALTER TABLE table_name ROW_FORMAT=Dynamic;

But it doesn't seem to change.

Please help.

Comment: DYNAMIC is the default (since 10.2.2). You're sure it's not set to that already? And the table is an XtraDB or InnoDB table? Also all the docs show it used in upper case text - have you tried that?  See https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/xtradbinnodb-storage-formats/

Comment: when i check select * from infromatin_scheme it indicates this table's row format is set to Compact!  its InnoDB

Comment: Backing up a step... What was the reason for even attempting the change?

Comment: In my case, the tables were created prior to DYNAMIC being instantiated as the default. So I got a request to update them to said default, for various reasons. However the alter statements both report no errors and don't actually change anything.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to make a dump, change it, and import the dump. Assuming it's "compact" before:

```
export DB=""

mysqldump -u root -p ${DB} > db_backup.sql && \
sed -i 's:ROW_FORMAT=COMPACT:ROW_FORMAT=DYNAMIC:g' db_backup.sql && \
mysql -u root -p ${DB} < db_backup.sql
```